# Performance hit of double dereferencing Reference types in C#

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Recently, I started working on a project where many reference parameters are passed around by reference. I've looked into a lot of the code and the majority of these methods could lose the `ref` parameter. Although the code functions fine, I was wondering what kind of performance hit there might be by double dereferencing every argument rather than just passing the reference by value.

For example, this code:

```
public void EmptyList(ref List<string> test)
{
    test.Clear();
}
```

VS this:

```
public void EmptyList(List<string> test)
{
    test.Clear();
}
```

### EDIT

After reading what Nicholas Carey had to say, I tried the same thing with the code above. This was the resulting assembly:

```
            EmptyList(ref List<string> test)
00000028  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
0000002b  mov         ecx,dword ptr [eax] 
0000002d  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx 
0000002f  call        719210C4


            EmptyList(List<string> test)
00000028  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
0000002b  cmp         dword ptr [ecx],ecx 
0000002d  call        71920FD4
```

Comment: Probably none that you would notice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference calling by explicit reference and calling by implicit reference is the difference between the `lea` (Load Effective Address) instruction and the `mov` ('Move') instruction.

AFAIK, on any modern processor, both of these instructions, in the form used, execute in a single clock cycle, so the difference is pretty much moot.

Here's the code generated (debug mode) for the call by [explicit] reference:

```
            FooBar( ref o ) ;
00000035  lea         ecx,[ebp-40h] 
00000038  call        FFD0B008 
0000003d  nop
```

And here's the code generated (debug mode) for the call by [implicit] reference:

```
            FooBar( o ) ;
0000003a  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
0000003d  call        FFD3B008 
00000042  nop
```

The code generated for the called method/function is identical in either case.

Here's the sample code I used, FWIW:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main( string[] args )
  {
    object o = null ;
    FooBar( ref o ) ;
  }

  private static void FooBar( ref object o )
  {
  }

}
```

IMHO, omit the `ref` keyword unless it's actually needed: all it really does is add semantic noise to the equation.

Comment: How did you get these assembly listings? I would expect to see CIL and not native x86 for this type of analysis. (Thanks btw)

Comment: Set a breakpoint. Fire up the debugger. When you hit the break point, open the disassembly window: either via the menu at Debug..Windows..Disassembly or the keyboard, [CTL]+[ALT]+D will get you there.

Comment: +1. All of the answers are right, but this actually answers the question that was asked with hard data.

Comment: @NicholasCarey sometimes the answers are too simple! Nice job.

Comment: @ttymatty - If I am not mistaken after your code is converted into CLR code its translated into machine language.

Comment: @Ramhound Certainly. But when analyzing code you need to decide which level to analyze: the C#, CIL, or x86 asm. Like reading a book for school, you can 1) browse the table of contents 2) read the cliff notes or 3) read the actual book. Each level gives more detail but takes longer to parse and absorb. x86 certainly gives us an exact answer here with `lea` vs `mov`.

Comment: After duplicating your test with some work done inside the method on the ref argument, the assembly code seems to show the second dereference call. If the argument is not used in the method, I assume the compiler optimizes that second dereference.

Answer (score 3):

The performance difference would likely be completely unnoticed, if it exists at all.  I would personally decide whether to pass the "reference parameters" by reference or by value by *functional requirements*, not performance differences.

Passing a reference type using `ref` has a strong implication to the caller.  The assumption is that your reference may change.  This has a distinct implication to the usage of your API, and a strong suggestion that you may be changing values.  If this is not the case, pass the reference by value to avoid the confusion, as it will lead to more maintainable, understandable code.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to know if I could present the argument to remove them more than "it's confusing and unnecessary" (which is enough for me).

Comment: @scottm Technically, the performance is likely to be nearly identical.  In both cases, you're effectively passing a memory location, which is going to be the same amount of copying either way... I suspect you'd never see the difference in a profiler, as it'd be so microscopic from a performance standpoint to be undetectable.

Comment: confusing, unnecessary, and likely makes the code more fragile.